# Distro Customisation And Middleware Software Inclusion

Tags: linux, opensuse, distributions, susestudio

I have been very recently introduced to UNIX/LINUX and I am overwhelmed by the sheer power.
I am a CS Graduate student and for my final year project I want to make an artificially intelligent Linux Distro.

While I can achieve the AI Part, I am confused about the customizing and OS. My initial thought was to use SUSE Studio to create a custom version to suit my needs, however I have a few queries.

- Say I install the SUSE in a virtual machine and customize it to it's
  brim and add middleware software to it. Then can I make it a distro
  from the installed version?
- If it is not possible with SUSE what would be your suggested oS?
- I would like to customize everything that is graphically visible to
  an user (boot screen, UI etc) and I would like to add my own software
  that starts up with the OS or as a background service.
- I will not customize the kernel although there is a probability that
  I might need to tweak it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fedora/Centos Kickstart system, which may work in SuSe too,  allows you to install additional packages, run scripts etc instead of the default CD scripts.

You can create UI based installs with zenity to ask for user parameters. This would ensure your customised settings/packages are what an end user gets.

As for the actual customization - almost any component of this can be customized as the source code is available. This is a matter of time spent on it - and time spend reading up the various parts.

Comment: Can I turn a Suse/Fedora installation into a distro/bootable disk, with all my softwares and customisations in place?

Comment: You would have to write the packages you want, and installation code in a ks config. As far as I know - there isn't an automatic way to do this. Building a VM with your settings and distributing the VM disk image may work for you, and there are tools for converting a physical installation to a VM.